# AVAssetReader doesn't read whole file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, avfoundation

I am reading audio assets from the iPod library on iOS with an AVAssetReader and AVAssetReaderTrackOutput. However, when i read the data and put the chunks back together, the file isn't exactly the same. A few kB are missing, and therefore the audio file won't play back.

Here is the code i use to extract the audio data

```
// Copy next audio samples
CMSampleBufferRef buffer = [[reader_.outputs objectAtIndex:0] copyNextSampleBuffer];

// Extract bytes from buffer
CMBlockBufferRef dataBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(buffer);

size_t bufLen = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(dataBuffer);
UInt8 buf[bufLen];

CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(dataBuffer, 0, bufLen, buf);

// Pass data to delegate
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(assetStream:hasDataAvailable:)]) {
    [delegate assetStream:self hasDataAvailable:[NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:bufLen]];
}

// Invalidate buffer
CMSampleBufferInvalidate(buffer);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem you're seeing, but I suspect that CMBlockBuffer functions only copy audio stream packets, leaving out the audio file header, which contains the information necessary to decode the packets. Did you compare the input/output files in a hex editor?

Comment: Yes, this question is old. You have to retrieve the headers (audio stream description) with other methods. The block buffer is just raw audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep I guessed right. The `copyNextSampleBuffer` does omit the AAC header, and therefore the media player API can't process the file.

You can copy the stream description with other methods.

Comment: Old question, I know, but did what methods did you end up using to get the stream description. Can't find anything in my initial so search.